# Android: Drawing bounding box on object in bitmap

Tags: java, android, image-processing

I have a black and white threshold bitmap. How will I detect and draw a bounding box around an object? For example:

[image: Threshold Bitmap]

The red box that is the box that I need to have drawn. The box is there because in this bitmap, the background is black, and inside the box is where the majority of the actual image (white) is. How would I get the app to detect and draw the bounding box?

Comment: you'll have to teach your computer that this is an "object". did you draw this rectangle manually? it doesn't look like it's the output of another software

Comment: Yes I drew the rectangle manually. Also, can you help me with "teaching the computer that this is an 'object?'"

Comment: no, because I don't know what makes this an object for you. for example I don't know why you excluded the other white spots on the right side, but included the small stuff on the bottom. if you can find a logical or numerical rule for that you can tell your computer. you could for example create a bounding box around the two largest blobs and include small spots that are close enough. but that might not work for other images...

Comment: I'm trying to solve a similar problem, did you find something?